Help identifying a highschool reality show on MTV
I remember that I saw a reality show once on MTV, the satellite television channel. 
I have went through the List of programs broadcast by MTV but I couldn't find it.
This series is about a group of high school students who go to a large room where they sit and talk. In addition each person has to talk about something which bothers him/her until he or she cries.
Some part of it included touching, since first they are shown as happy having fun, but later they talk about stress, depression, parent issues etc.
I have probably seen this 4 years ago. The show is definitely not old; estimated between 2002 and 2010.
The episodes were short; possibly each less than 30 minutes.

It sounds a lot like If You Really Knew Me, but each episode was an hour long.

@Walt, wow you found it; please convert your comment to an answer. Too bad it ran for 12 episodes only.

If You Really Knew Me, which ran for only one season on MTV in 2010.

Students from each [school] clique participate in Challenge Day, which is a program designed to break down stereotypes and unite students in schools. At Challenge Day, students from all walks of life gather together in one room. Then each student is assigned to a group where they must reveal something personal about themselves. 

This lead to some pretty emotional scenes. Here's a clip:



